# How to create batch script and run it using ShellEd plugin in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, batch-file, eclipse-plugin

I have recently installed ShellEd plugin in eclipse but don't know how to setup RunConfiguration and Create and run a batch script on ecplise...How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need [basheclipse](http://sourceforge.net/projects/basheclipse/) to debug it requires ShellEd.

Refer this post for step by step instruction. [is-there-a-gui-debugger-for-shell-scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131491/is-there-a-gui-debugger-for-shell-scripts)